# Как создать config и правило UrlManager в Module для SubModule?

Tags: php, yii2

Как создать `config` и правило `UrlManager` в `Module` для `SubModule`?

Основной config, становится слишком громоздким...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле /web/index.php
вы можете добавлять любое количество файлов с всевозможными конфигами.
К примеру у вас есть конфиг

```
return [
'id' => 'test',
'name'=>'test',
'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'keyPrefix' => 'test',
        'useMemcached' => true,
    ],
    'logging' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\Logging',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'nickcv\mandrill\Mailer',
        'apikey' => 'QsQ7THETFKNqQxnM5vR6TA',
    ]
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
],
'modules' => [

]
```

И вы хотите все свои роуты хранить в другом файле, или разделить их по файлам. Вам необходимо создать в папке конфига еще один файл, к примеру routes

```
return [
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            '/test' => '/test/test',
            '/test' => '/test/test',
            '/test' => '/test/test',
        ],
    ],

],
```

];

и потом смерджить два этих конфига в файле /web/index.php

```
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/routes.php'));
```